# CakePHP 3 - Use data in an Element

Tags: cakephp, element, cakephp-3.0

I just started using CakePHP, version 3. What I liked to start with is creating a menu based on a database table.

For creating a menu, I have seen that it should be placed inside the Element folder and called in 'default.ctp'. No problems here.

The problem is: How can I retrieve the data from the table while I'm not working in the controller, using the power of CakePHP? I can't find an example or something.

Inside 'Element/Menus/main.ctp' I do something like this (I know the link is not correct):

```
<?php
            $menus = $this->requestAction('/Menus/index');
            foreach ($menus as $menu) {
                ?>
                <li><?= $this->Html->link('Menu', ['controller' => 'Menus', 'action' => 'index', '_full' => true]); ?></li>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
```

I try to get the data by calling 'requestAction' but it doesn't seem to be the right way.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. Can this be overused?